# Restrict jenkins only on localhost with docker and nginx

Tags: nginx, jenkins, docker, localhost

I have application with a couple of running on docker containers (nginx, db, php, ..) connected together with docker-compose. Now i want to use jenkins to build this app on production. Im am not sure how to connect jenkins container with nginx and limit it only to localhost.

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream jenkins {
        server jenkins:8080;
}
```

**sites-enabled/default.conf**

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name jenkins.example.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass              http://jenkins;
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

**jenkins Dockerfile**

```
FROM jenkins

ENV JENKINS_OPTS --httpListenAddress=172.17.0.1
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
jenkins:
  ports:
    - "8080:8080" 
nginx:
  links:
    - jenkins
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  ...
```

I get 502 error. When i change --httpListenAddress to 0.0.0.0 it works but then is not limited only to localhost. 172.17.0.1 is the docker gateway.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 usually means listen on all interfaces. Have you tried 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes i tried No success. Docker listens to 172.x.x.x

Answer (score 3):

Remove the ports entry from jenkins. The ports entry is only needed to expose the port of the docker container to the localhost.

To expose the port to another docker container, linking them is sufficient. In your nginx links: you have already mentioned jenkins. Hence you don't need to have the ports entry in your jenkins.

```
...
jenkins:
  ...
nginx:
  links:
    - jenkins
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try use it

```
jenkins:
  ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080" 
nginx:
  links:
    - jenkins
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```